# Chrome DevTools Protocol - Network Events after page load

Tags: chrome-devtools-protocol

I'm trying to use the [**chrome-remote-interface**](https://github.com/cyrus-and/chrome-remote-interface) package to register URL's requested by a page, through the Chrome DevTools Protocol.

It works fine until the page loads. After the page loads, I can't get the requests. For example: Ajax, Google Analytics Requests, ...

Is it possible to have the requested URLs after page load with Chrome DevTools Protocol?

Comment: https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#event-requestWillBeSent

Answer (score 0):

Some of the requests are not done with classic HTTP requests (which are the ones handled by the `Network` domain. However, youtube's Ajax "navigation" for example, could be tracked by the `Page.frameRequestedNavigation` event, so it might also work for Google Analytics.